# Extract instances from perminute timeseries data where the POWER value is 0 continuously for greater than 0 minutes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series

I have huge time series dataset containing TIME, POWER as columns, I'm taking this dataset in window of 30 minutes and inside each window if POWER value is 0 for greater than 10 minutes continuously, then I'll store the start_time, end_time, duration, and number of occurrences of such instance within the window in the dictionary.

```
    window_size = 30
    # Identify anomalous instances within the window
    anomalous_ranges = []
    for i in range(0, len(df) - 1, window_size):
            batch = df.iloc[i:i+window_size]
            # print(batch)
            start_time = None
            end_time = None
            for idx, row in batch.iterrows():
                p = row['ACTIVEPOWER']
                if p == 0:
                    if start_time is None:
                        start_time = row['TIME']
                    else:
                        end_time = row['TIME']
                else:    
                    if start_time and end_time is not None:
                        duration = (pd.to_datetime(end_time) - pd.to_datetime(start_time)).total_seconds() / 60.0
                        print(duration)
                        label = 'Zero Values'
                        if duration >= 10:
                            anomalous_ranges.append((start_time, end_time, duration,label))
                        start_time = None
```

Output:
anomalous_ranges

```
Start Time  End Time    Duration (Minutes)  Remarks
0   2023-04-19 01:37:30 2023-04-19 01:53:30 16.0    Zero Values
1   2023-04-19 14:37:30 2023-04-19 14:50:30 13.0    Zero Values
2   2023-04-19 15:37:30 2023-04-19 16:03:30 26.0    Zero Values
3   2023-04-20 05:16:30 2023-04-20 05:26:30 10.0    Zero Values
4   2023-04-21 14:37:30 2023-04-21 14:49:30 12.0    Zero Values
5   2023-04-22 23:07:30 2023-04-22 23:25:30 18.0    Zero Values
6   2023-04-24 20:07:30 2023-04-24 20:26:30 19.0    Zero Values
7   2023-04-25 11:07:30 2023-04-25 11:18:30 11.0    Zero Values
...
```

in the dataset, there are more instances which are not getting captured here.
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5SxhU.png)
if you see only red block instances getting captured but after the first red block, in the next window the power is 0 continuously for greater than 10 minute

Comment: Please explain better what help do you need

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.